# Cannot get Kubernetes Pod Logs

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, networking

I have 2 nodes, 1 master and 1 worker. They are not able to communicate via private IP as they are on different networks. I have set up a wireguard VPN between the 2 nodes, on IPs

```
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

When I run ping commands, they are able to communicate with each other, no problem.

When I initialise my kubernetes cluster using:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.0.3 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.0.3
```

And then join my worker node, I am able to see all the pods etc come up as I'd expect (everything bar the 1 kube proxy pod is on master node as expected), however I am not able to see the logs of said pod?

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

How do you view the pods' logs?

Besides, `kubeadm init` is wrong, network range of `--pod-network-cidr` option mustn't overlap with IP of nodes in K8S Cluster.

You can change to another local network range as follows

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.16.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.0.3 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.0.3
```

Comment: to view the logs, I was using kubectl logs -n <ns> <pod name>

Comment: After having repeated, using the 172.16 cidr block, I get the same issue. I'm using cilium as a CNI, and it appears to come up correctly, but I still cannot access the logs of the pods on a worker node

Comment: Sorry for the extra comment; is it possible this issue is related to Kubernetes getting confused by multiple network interfaces? I have the basic ubuntu interface, as well as "wg0" which is the wireguard VPN which provides the private IPs

Comment: What was the response you received?